# Angular 5 Mat-Stepper with dynamic form

Tags: angular, angular5

Is it possible to add the dynamic for logic into a material stepper?

I'm using:

1. api
   `import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';`
2. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

How can I call

```
<app-dynamic-form [questions]="questions"></app-dynamic-form>
```

into the form group of mat-stepper?

Comment: you can use the `@ViewChild()` functionality to get access to Children Components. 

I think you use the `@ContentChild()` functionality for sibling components. 

there's a  "...Children" utility as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this for my own project where I need to feed the stepper with a whole lot of questions, one for every step. So after a long time trying, I managed to put together what we can find in https://material.angular.io about steppers, Deborah Kurata's Reactive forms from PluralSight and the stackblitz demo from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46469671/revisions, here:

**For Your Template**

```
                <mat-step *ngFor="let stepp of steps?.controls; let i=index" formGroupName="{{i}}" [stepControl]="steps?.get([i])">
                    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
                    <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <div>
                    <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                    </div>
                </mat-step>

    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

**For Your Component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

    import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test-questions',
      templateUrl: './test-questions.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test-questions.component.css']
    })
    export class TestQuestionsComponent implements OnInit {
      isLinear = true;

      questionsForm: FormGroup;

       get steps(): FormArray{
        return<FormArray>this.questionsForm.get('steps'); // Must be <FormArrary> so it's not abstract control
      } 
  constructor(private testService: TestService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {


    this.questionsForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      steps: this._formBuilder.array([
        // this.buildStepper()
        this._formBuilder.group({
          firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
        }),
        this._formBuilder.group({
          firstCtrl: ['asfsf', Validators.email]
        })
      ]) // Must be using form array
    });

  }

}
```